# deploy containers on swarm cluster using compose file without using docker machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have build a swarm cluster without using docker machine. if we use docker machine then we can deploy using following

eval "$(docker-machine env --swarm )"
$ docker-compose up

but without docker-machine how to access swarm master to deploy containers using compose file?

Regards
Shuja